# Extends a component to create the logic in another

Tags: reactjs

I have a component that have some logic and I want the same component without the logic inside. I want to build a pure component without any logic and I want to extends this component to put the original logic so I can use the component with the original logic or the component without any logic. It's like I need a subset of the component and I don't want to copy. I want to extract the difference so I can you the complete component or just part of.

Can I do this in react besides treat lhe component without logic as the children of the component with the logic? What would be the best away to do this? I don't think that is a HOC problem.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this approach can help you: https://jsfiddle.net/ginollerena/69z2wepo/71540/

```
const TextElement = (props) => (
        <input type="text"            
               defaultValue={props.value}
               onChange={props.handleChange}
               placeholder={props.placeholder}/>
);

const TextAreaElement = (props) => (
        <textarea             
               defaultValue={props.value}
               onChange={props.handleChange}
               placeholder={props.placeholder}/>

);

let Mixing = InnerComponent => class extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { value :''}
    this._handleChange = this._handleChange.bind(this);
  }

  _handleChange(e) {
    const value = e.target.value;
    this.setState({value:value});
  }

  render(){
    return(<InnerComponent value={this.state.value} handleChange={this._handleChange} />)
  }

};

const MyTextComponent = Mixing(TextElement);
const MyTextAreaComponent = Mixing(TextAreaElement);



ReactDOM.render(
  <MyTextComponent  />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for the answer but It isn't what I'm looking for. This is more like HOC and and don't want this. Let me try to explain better. Think of a Tab component. I want a tab component that the logic of change the active tab it isn't inside the tab component. But I want a component that manages this active tab, extending this original tab component without logic. So I can use the original component or the component with the logic? Did I make this more clear?